# How to use pinax django user accounts in a normal django project?

Tags: python, django, pinax

Tried to integrate pinax django user accounts to a normal django project. The project is functional. I am using pinax-theme-bootstrap for this app. But I am not able to see any styling change in the site. this is my sitebase.html

```
{% extends "theme_bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}


{% block site_brand %}<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url "home" %}">Try</a>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav %}

{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}

{% endblock %}`
```

My home.html is extending sitebase.html. Please help me to fix this or let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks for any reply...

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting? and is your settings.py file is configured correctly to detect templates in your project?

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py use named urls.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('your_app.views',
    url(r'account/signup//$', 'your_view_function', name='account_signup'),
)
```

Then in your template use `{% url account_signup %}.`

If this is not the case, please paste your template and url code here

Comment: Please see the modified question.

Comment: Are you sure that `TEMPLATES` settings in your project is detecting the pinax templates